# Timeout after 30000ms in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, testing, timeout, case

I'm trying to open a page (target: /selenium#/login), but I keep getting a timeout error. The page seems to be done loading so I don't get why I keep getting the error. Also, the error only occurs when I'm playing the entire test suite. When I try to run each test case individually, the error doesn't appear.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the error doesn't occur when I open a new tab right before the next test case starts (before the open command is read), so each test case has to be on an entirely new tab/window. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OezAj.png

Comment: Try putting in some of your test code. That way we can work with something tangible.

Comment: I'm using the IDE for firefox. Forgot to mention, the error doesn't occur when I open a new tab right before the next test case starts (before the open command is read). Also, the rest of the commands after open run fine after the error occurs. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/pF2e6iU.png